# Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, ssms, union-all

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

This seems like quite the common error but every result that I look up has a group by clause or statement. My example does not. Below is the code used. Any ideas as to how to resolve this error?

```sql
 select year, qtr, area, industry, ownership, employment
 from indstry
 where ( area = '32001' or area = '32005' or area = '32007' or area = 
 '32009' or area = '32011' or area = '32013' or area ='32015' or area = 
 '32017' or area = '32019' or area = '32021' or area = '32023' or area = 
 '32027' or area = '32033' ) and year ='2016'
 union all
 select year, NULL as qtr, '99999' as Area, NULL as industry, NULL as 
 ownership, sum (employment) as employment
 From industry
 where ( area = '32001' or area = '32005' or area = '32007' or area = 
 '32009' or area = '32011' or area = '32013' or area ='32015' or area = 
 '32017' or area = '32019' or area = '32021' or area = '32023' or area = 
 '32027' or area = '32033' ) and year ='2016'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the second part of your query: `year` column must be either grouped by in the `group by` clause or aggregated in the `select` statement:

The other columns (`qtr`, `Area`, `industry` and `ownership`) can be skipped since you provide explicit values for them, but year` column comes from the table and must be handled accordingly.

### Solution 1

Group `year` column (adding `group by (year)` at the end of the query):

```sql
select year, qtr, area, industry, ownership, employment
from indstry
where ( area = '32001' or area = '32005' or area = '32007' or area = 
'32009' or area = '32011' or area = '32013' or area ='32015' or area = 
'32017' or area = '32019' or area = '32021' or area = '32023' or area = 
'32027' or area = '32033' ) and year ='2016'
union all
select year, NULL as qtr, '99999' as Area, NULL as industry, NULL as 
ownership, sum (employment) as employment
From industry
where ( area = '32001' or area = '32005' or area = '32007' or area = 
'32009' or area = '32011' or area = '32013' or area ='32015' or area = 
'32017' or area = '32019' or area = '32021' or area = '32023' or area = 
'32027' or area = '32033' ) and year ='2016'
group by (year)
```

### Solution 2

Aggregate year column with `max`, `min`, `avg` etc. (for example changing `year` to `max(year)` in the `select` statement of the second part of your query):

```sql
select year, qtr, area, industry, ownership, employment
from indstry
where ( area = '32001' or area = '32005' or area = '32007' or area = 
'32009' or area = '32011' or area = '32013' or area ='32015' or area = 
'32017' or area = '32019' or area = '32021' or area = '32023' or area = 
'32027' or area = '32033' ) and year ='2016'
union all
select max(year), NULL as qtr, '99999' as Area, NULL as industry, NULL as 
ownership, sum (employment) as employment
From industry
where ( area = '32001' or area = '32005' or area = '32007' or area = 
'32009' or area = '32011' or area = '32013' or area ='32015' or area = 
'32017' or area = '32019' or area = '32021' or area = '32023' or area = 
'32027' or area = '32033' ) and year ='2016'
```